# Should I make a call to a brownfield API asynchronous if I know the API does I/O at some point?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on a project that makes use of an old API we wrote (i.e. not third-party, but not under development currently).  The old API does unmanaged I/O operations: it connects to a middle tier server using a COM DLL via runtime callable wrappers (RCWs).  This new project itself is going to be an API for a new application that, like I said, makes use of the old API; however, I'd like to expose asynchronous methods wherever appropriate because I'm not yet sure how I will use the new API.  If I use it in a web application, for example, I want to make sure I'm not blocking threads unnecessarily waiting on I/O ops that are happening deep down inside the COM DLL.

Here is what my new application would look like:

```
------------------------------
|  CLIENT (WIN32, WEB, ETC.)  |
-------------------------------
------------------------------
|         NEW API             |
-------------------------------
------------------------------
|         OLD API             |
-------------------------------
------------------------------
|         COM DLL             |
-------------------------------
```

This is really simplified and makes it look like the only purpose for the new API is to wrap the old API, but the new API is a separate application that has its own business logic and uses the old API for a percentage of the operations.

I've been reading a lot about the appropriate use of async/await and in particular with brownfield applications; [Stephen Cleary's MSDN Magazine article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for example is very helpful.    I'm struggling in my case, though.  If I'm not *directly* making use of a truly-asynchronous I/O method, e.g. [HttpClient.GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync(v=vs.110).aspx), but I know (or am reasonably sure) the COM DLL is doing I/O without a thread, is there [still no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)?  In other words, does the thread get relinquished as soon as it hits the I/O operation deep down inside the COM DLL called via the old synchronous API?

Here's some sample code.  This is the old API:

```
public class OldApi
{
    public bool TryCheckOutDocument(int docNum, out Document document)
    {
        // use COM dll to "check out" the doc.
    }

    public bool TryCheckInDocument(Document document)
    {
        // " " "check in" the doc.
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public int DocNum { get; }
    public object OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the new API:

```
public class NewApi
{
    public async Task ConvertDocsAsync(IEnumerable<int> docNums)
    {
        var oldApi = new OldApi();

        Parallel.ForEach(docNums, async (docNum) =>
        {
            Document doc = null;

            if (await Task.Run(() => !oldApi.TryCheckOutDocument(docNum, out doc)))
                throw new Exception($"blah blah: {docNum}");

            doc.OtherData = "this represents the conversion";

            if (await Task.Run(() => !oldApi.TryCheckInDocument(doc)))
                throw new Exception($"blah blah: {docNum}");
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using `Task.Run` to call the synchronous methods in the old API.  When they hit I/O ops, will the thread be relinquished?  If not, is there a better way to use async/await to ensure the most-efficient use of asynchrony?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm using Task.Run to call the synchronous methods in the old API. When they hit I/O ops, will the thread be relinquished? If not, is there a better way to use async/await to ensure the most-efficient use of asynchrony?

No; I'm afraid that since the old API is synchronous, you can't "force" it to be asynchronous.

> If I'm not directly making use of a truly-asynchronous I/O method... but I know (or am reasonably sure) the COM DLL is doing I/O without a thread, is there still no thread? In other words, does the thread get relinquished as soon as it hits the I/O operation deep down inside the COM DLL called via the old synchronous API?

All I/O is inherently asynchronous, but in this case the first synchronous call is blocking a thread on that I/O. So even if the COM DLL is asynchronous, the old API is only exposing synchronous APIs - the old API would be blocking a thread.

And on a side note, using `async` with `Parallel` is a sure recipe for a painful experience.

Your best bet for now is to just keep it synchronous:

```
Parallel.ForEach(docNums, docNum =>
{
  Document doc = null;

  if (!oldApi.TryCheckOutDocument(docNum, out doc))
    throw new Exception($"blah blah: {docNum}");

  doc.OtherData = "this represents the conversion";

  if (!oldApi.TryCheckInDocument(doc))
    throw new Exception($"blah blah: {docNum}");
});
```

until the old API is updated with asynchronous methods, at which point you can do asynchronous concurrency:

```
var tasks = docNums.Select(async docNum =>
{
  Document doc = await oldApi.CheckOutDocumentAsync(docNum);
  doc.OtherData = "this represents the conversion";
  await oldApi.CheckInDocumentAsync(doc);
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: What if my new project contains async-ready calls, e.g. `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`.  How should I call them using my parallel approach?  The most important thing here as that multiple things can get done at once, taking advantage of multi-processors.  Secondary is threading efficiency (for web-based clients).  Obviously by using TPL I'm obviating concerns about UI responsiveness (for UI-based clients).  So should if I don't want to mix parallel and async, should I avoid async-ready methods, like `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`, and just use their synchronous counterparts?

Comment: I would use the asynchronous concurrency approach. If you need *parallelism* with asynchrony, then look into TPL Dataflow.

Comment: So in modern computers with multiple processors, isn't it enough to use the concurrency approach in order to achieve parallelism?  In other words, don't "concurrent" operations naturally happen on multiple threads running on whatever processor the OS deems appropriate, thus effectively running in parallel?

Comment: I use the term "concurrent" to mean "doing more than one thing at a time", and "parallelism" to mean "multiple threads in parallel". Thus, asynchrony and parallelism are different forms of concurrency.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.